# How to highlight a reply in a discussion forum based on a condition in Flat.aspx

Tags: discussion-board, design

In the `Flat.aspx` page of a discussion forum, I have to highlight the reply if the poster belongs to a certain group. How do I achieve that?

I tried modifying the `Profile.xsl` file that the list view uses, but none of the changes are getting reflected. Am I looking at the wrong xsl file? Or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

This could be accomplished on client side.
Below is provided full solution description.

Script for highlighting discussion list replies:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(highlightDiscussion, "sp.js");



function highlightDiscussion()
{
   var discussionGroupId = 3;
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current;
   var groups = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
   var group = groups.getById(discussionGroupId);   //
   this.groupUsers = group.get_users();
   clientContext.load(groupUsers);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}


function resolveUserForReply(replyItem)
{
     var userEntry = {};
     var replyRow = replyItem.closest('tr');
     var userUrl = replyRow.find('a').attr('href');
     userEntry.ID = userUrl.match(/ID=([^&]+)/)[1];
     return userEntry;
}


function highlightReply(replyItem)
{
    replyItem.css({'background-color': '#00ffcc'});
}

function highlightReplyForUser(userId)
{
    $('div[class^="ExternalClass"]').each(function(index) {
        var user = resolveUserForReply($(this));
        if(userId == user.ID)
           highlightReply($(this)); 
    });
}


function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var ie = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
    while (ie.moveNext()) {
       var user = ie.get_current();
       highlightReplyForUser(user.get_id());
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

---

**How to make it work:**

1. Save this script as a file DiscussionsHighlight.js and place it to LAYOUTS folder
2. Embed specified file and jquery files into discussion list, for example add it to Flat.aspx like shown below:

[image]

**Results**

On picture below is displayed discussion list with highlighted replies for users who belongs to specific group (see parameter `discussionGroupId` in script )

[image]